# I disabled an interface in vyatta, how do I enable it?

Tags: interface, vyatta

I entered `set interfaces eth0 disabled` which worked. `show interfaces` shows that the interface is administratively down. However I can figure out how to bring it back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete interfaces eth0 disabled
```